# Yii2 populate update form with values stored in array

Tags: php, activerecord, model-view-controller, yii2

I have created a form with the following fields and use json encode before saving to a single database field.

Now I need to populate the fields when using the update form however I am unsure as i can't find any yii2 example.

```
<?= $form->field( $model, 'seo_information[field1]' )
          ->textInput( [ 'maxlength' => 255 ] )
          ->label('Array Field 1) ?>

<?= $form->field( $model, 'seo_information[field2]' )
         ->textInput( [ 'maxlength' => 255 ] )
         ->label('Array Field 2') ?>

<?= $form->field( $model, 'seo_information[field3]' )
         ->textInput( [ 'maxlength' => 255 ] )
         ->label('Array Field 3') ?>
```

Controller Create Code

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new Article();
    $model->user_id = Yii::$app->user->id;

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) 
    {
        $seo_information = $_POST['Article']['seo_information'];
        $model->seo_information = json_encode($seo_information); 
        $model->save();
        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
    } 
    else 
    {
        return $this->render('create', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you show how you do json_encode? Is it in controller or model?

Comment: `public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model = new Article();
        $model->user_id = Yii::$app->user->id;

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) 
        {
            $seo_information = $_POST['Article']['seo_information'];
            $model->seo_information = json_encode($seo_information); 
            $model->save();
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
        } 
        else 
        {
            return $this->render('create', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }
    }` Could do with some validation.

Comment: Oh... please put that into your question! Just edit the question and insert the code, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
else 
{
     $model->seo_information = json_decode($model->seo_information, true); 
     return $this->render('create', [
         'model' => $model,
     ]); 
}
```

This works also if the value in the db is NULL.